# Answer me please; Tor doesn't work!

Tags: torsocks

Russian text:

Доброе утро !

```
    Я 2 месяца не пользовался Tor Browser... А потом, возникла необходимость воспользоваться Tor Browser, и я запустил этот броузер (ранее был установлен в моём
```

компьютере; в дирректории: C:\Program Files\Tor Browser). Но, после запуска Tor Browser - он так и не запустился ! Я ждал, когда броузер запустится до конца,
но он так и не запустился...! Я проделеал три попытки запуска; и скопировал в буфер обмена - три отчёта (об неудавшихся попытках) !
               Предлагаю Вашему вниманию этих три отчёта, которые прикрепил к своему письму и отправил к Вам по E-mail. Помогите мне пожалуйста ! Помогите мне
пожалуйста решить проблему запуска и запустить Tor Browser в моём компьютере ! У меня операционная система Microsoft Windows - Версия 6.1 (сборка 7601: Service
Pack 1); Windows7 Professional.
         Ответьте мне пожалуйста ! Заранее благодарен.

С уважением, Алексей.

English text:

Good morning!

I have 2 months did not use the Tor Browser Bundle. Then, it became necessary to use the Tor Browser Bundle, and I launched this browser (was previously installed  in my computer; in the directory: C:\Program Files\Tor Browser). But, after running the Tor Browser Bundle-he does not start! I've been waiting for when the browser  starts to end,
but he did not start ...! I prodeleal three attempts to launch; and copied to the Clipboard-three report (about the failed attempt)!
                   I bring to your attention these three report that attached to his letter and sent to you by E-mail. Help me please! Help me Please solve the problem start and run Tor Browser in my computer! I have the Microsoft Windows operating system version 6.1 (build 7601: Service Pack 1); Windows7 Professional.

Answer me please! Beforehand grateful.

Regards, Alex.

```
09.04.2016 0:28:09.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09.04.2016 0:28:09.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09.04.2016 0:28:17.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
09.04.2016 0:28:17.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
09.04.2016 0:28:17.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to     109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:28:17.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:28:17.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:28:17.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.99.11.54:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:28:17.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:41213 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:28:17.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:28:18.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:41835 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:28:18.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.13:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:28:19.100 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 104.131.108.182:56880 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:28:19.100 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:29:14.500 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09.04.2016 0:29:14.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09.04.2016 0:29:14.500 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09.04.2016 0:29:56.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09.04.2016 0:30:03.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:30:03.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:30:03.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.99.11.54:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:30:03.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:30:03.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:41213 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:30:03.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:41835 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:30:03.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:30:03.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.13:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:30:04.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 104.131.108.182:56880 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:30:04.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:30:18.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09.04.2016 0:30:18.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09.04.2016 0:30:18.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

---

```
09.04.2016 0:17:40.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
09.04.2016 0:17:40.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
09.04.2016 0:17:40.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
09.04.2016 0:17:40.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
09.04.2016 0:17:40.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
09.04.2016 0:19:39.200 [NOTICE] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up. (waiting for circuit) 
09.04.2016 0:22:13.900 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09.04.2016 0:22:13.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09.04.2016 0:22:13.900 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09.04.2016 0:22:15.400 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
09.04.2016 0:22:47.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09.04.2016 0:22:47.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09.04.2016 0:22:47.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09.04.2016 0:22:47.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09.04.2016 0:22:47.200 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Program Files\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.2" 
09.04.2016 0:22:57.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:22:57.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:22:57.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:22:57.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:22:57.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.99.11.54:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:22:57.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:41213 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:22:57.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.13:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:22:57.900 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:41835 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:22:58.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 104.131.108.182:56880 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:22:58.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
09.04.2016 0:23:17.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
09.04.2016 0:23:17.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
09.04.2016 0:23:17.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Comment: It looks like something is blocking your connections. Have you tried using bridges?

Comment: Russian: Вечером попозже сегодня помогу, тёзка! Стукнись мне в facebook. English: I'll be able to help you this evening abit later, contact me in facebook.

Comment: Alexey, спасибо за ответ…! А можно в Контакте…? А то я в Facebook пока ещё не активный. Или здесь можно, или через E-mail ! Ответьте мне пожалуйста! Заранее благодарен.

Comment: У меня МТС 4G интернет…

Comment: SuperSluether! Show me how you can try to use the bridges? Where do you start first? Help step by step everything run Tor to connect and connected to its hosting; that worked! Thanks in advance! Answer me!

Comment: @Alex я в ВК редко бываю ОЧЕНЬ - http://vk.com/netherworld  Конфиги свои все прикрепи к вопросу - torrc как минимум. Если их несколько - то все прикрепляй

Comment: Alexey, спасибо за ответы. Я вчера был в гостях, а сегодня на работе !
Завтра приеду домой и деинсталлирую заново Tor посл. версии; потом повторю попытку запуска - через своего провайдера (МТС) и, если не получится опять, то - после трёх попыток отправлю все три отчёта Вам, сохранив предварительно каждый! Также проверю синхронизацию по времени с сервером time.windows!

Comment: Alexey, скажите: в Контакте - можно все отчёты отправить обычными сообщениями (копировать-вставить) т.е. Как обычно переписываемся ?

Comment: Я забыл спросить про Tor Bundle - Ваше мнение!! И надо ли (можно ли его применять) в домашнем быту ??

Comment: @Alex на pastebin залейте логи, тор пользуюсь каждый день и Вам рекомендую! В ВК стукнитесь, но лучше все-таки Facebook

Comment: I don't speak Russian, but if you still need help with bridges, here's the website: https://bridges.torproject.org/

Comment: Alexey! Спасибо что откликаетесь…! Я решил проблему при запуске Tor броузер сам. Заработал… Произвёл синхронизацию с сервером time.eindows. Но у Меня кщё 1 вопрос, касаемый торрент трекеров… как теперь можно скачивать и обходить блокировки, чтобы было как раньше ? Например с трекеров - rutracker.org ! У меня установлен в компьютере стандартная прога Torrent и всё. Подскажите и помогите адаптироваться пожалуйста к современным условиям ! Alex.

Comment: Alexey Vesnin,  
Я забыл спросить про Tor Bundle - Ваше мнение!! И надо ли (можно ли его применять) в домашнем быту ??